# Insert and list data in onew View

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

What I am trying to do is to have one page to create new House and also diplsay all existing houses.
the code for the main view is :

```
@modelData.Models.SGHouse

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions
                                      {
                                        HttpMethod = "Post",
                                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                        UpdateTargetId = "HouseList"
                                    }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>SGHouse</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @*<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model._id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model._id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model._id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>*@

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.House, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.House, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.House, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
@Html.Partial("_Houses",Model)
```

The code for my Partial view to list all houses is :

```
@model IEnumerable<Data.Models.SGHouse>
<div id="HouseList">

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.House)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.House)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item._id }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item._id }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item._id })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
</div>
```

I am not sure what view to return from my controller, if I do :

```
public ActionResult Create()
            {
                return View();
            }
```

I get error from my partial view about model is null. 
If I use :

```
public ActionResult Create()
                {
                    return View(new SGHouse());
                }
```

Then I get error

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Data.Models.SGHouse', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Data.Models.SGHouse]'.

Any help how to resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: is your first view only for creating new? or is it for both create and edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one new Property in class like this

```
 public  class SGHouse
    {

        public List<SGHouse> ListSGHouse { get; set; }
    }
```

And in Constroller

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        SGHouse model = new SGHouse();
        List<SGHouse> LstSGHouse = new List<SGHouse>();
        LstSGHouse = //Just add list of SGHouse to this property
        model.ListSGHouse = LstSGHouse; //Assign above to this


        return View(model);
    }
```

In View Just Call like this

```
@Html.RenderPartial("_Houses", Model.ListSGHouse);
```

Make Sure to Check model is not null in your partial view

```
@if (Model != null)
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much , really appreciated.